# vba case criteria for pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, double-quotes

I'm trying to filter a pivot table and it depends on a user criteria, which are always 12 values.

To create the criteria I have a range of possible values and the following code creates a new column of 1 or 0, one meaning include in the filter:

```
For i = 123 To 5 Step -1
    Cells(i, 60).Value = 0
    If Cells(i, 59).Value = Criterio Then Cells(i, 60).Value = 1
    If Cells(i, 59).Value = Criterio Then Indicador = Indicador + 1
    If Indicador > 0 And Indicador <= 12 Then Cells(i, 60).Value = 1
    If Indicador = 1 Then PivotSelection = Criterio & Chr(34)
    If Indicador > 1 And Indicador < 12 Then PivotSelection = PivotSelection & "," & Chr(34) & Cells(i, 59).Value & Chr(34)
    If Indicador = 12 Then PivotSelection = PivotSelection & "," & Chr(34) & Cells(i, 59).Value
    If Indicador > 0 Then Indicador = Indicador + 1
Next i
```

So it returns a string like: "2012.01","2012.02","2012.03",...,"2012.12" for example.

I thought the best way is to filter the pivot is using CASE. The problem is that when I use this criteria in the CASE option, it is not working:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Table").PivotFields("CLOSING_MONTH"). _
    CurrentPage = "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Table").PivotFields("CLOSING_MONTH")
    For Each oPi In .PivotItems
        If oPi = "(blank)" Then Exit For
        Select Case oPi.Value
            Case PivotSelection
                If oPi.Visible = False Then oPi.Visible = True
            Case Else
                If oPi.Visible = True Then oPi.Visible = False
            End Select
    Next oPi
End With
```

Any idea?

Comment: If the problem is the double quote then you can use `Chr(34)` in vba. `Chr(34) & Criterio & Chr(34)`

Comment: I changed for:        If Indicador = 1 Then PivotSelection = Chr(34) & Criterio & Chr(34)
        If Indicador > 1 And Indicador <= 12 Then PivotSelection = PivotSelection & "," & Chr(34) & Cells(i, 59).Value & Chr(34) But the final result still has double quotation: ""2012.01","2012.02"" and the case statment doesn't work.....

Comment: I modify the code to avoid double quote but case still not working...

Comment: Well. The double quote probably isn't the problem then... When you say it's "not working" what do you mean? Does it just step into the else block? Have you tried `msgbox oPi.Value` just before the case statement to check the value is what you expect?

Comment: Isn't `PivotSelection` a list of several dates and `oPi` a single date?  Meaning that it will never match unless `PivotSelection` has only one value?  or... you find `oPi` within the `PivotSelection` string.

Comment: It does work (there are no errors) but it doesn't select what I want in the pivot table. The problem is that in the case statment, looks like if it doesn't recognize the PivotSelection criteria. The oPi.value is correct

Comment: I want to use PivotSelection as a set of valid values to be selected in the pivot.

Comment: I want to do someting like this example (taken from another question): With table.PivotFields("Division")
        For Each PvI In .PivotItems
            Select Case PvI.Name
            Case "DivA", "DivB", "DivC", "DivD", "DivE"
                PvI.Visible = True
            Case Else
                PvI.Visible = False
            End Select
        Next
    End With
End Sub. But creating the case criteria in a dymanic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead of `Select Case`

```
If (InStr(1, PivotSelection, oPi.Value)) Then
    oPi.Visible = True
Else
    oPi.Visible = False
End If
```